# MCFirebaseMessagingService absent from PushMessageManager.messagingService for Xamarin Binding, but not for test app with same native code

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android

I am currently making a Xamarin Binding (only Android for now) for MarketingCloudSDK 7.3.0 which is basically a wrapper in C#. So in java, I use the MarketingCloudSDK with the functions I need and I generate a lib (aar) that I use in my binding (C#). My problem is that everything related to push notifications does not work in the binding, but it works in my native test app (kotlin). For instance, I can find the device id in the MobilePush contact list when I use my native test app, but not with the binding. In both cases, I initialized MarketingCloud in the app's onCreate method.

When I added some logs, using *MarketingCloudSdk.getInstance().getSdkState()*, I did notice an important difference between both cases.

**Native**

```
"PushMessageManager": {
        "pushEnabled": true,
        "debugInfo": {
            "senderId": "myid......",
            "deviceToken": null,
            "firebaseApps": [],
            "c2dmReceiver": [
                {
                    "name": "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver",
                    "priority": 0
                }
            ],
            "instanceIdService": [],
            "messagingService": [
                {
                    "name": "com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.MCFirebaseMessagingService",
                    "priority": -1
                },
                {
                    "name": "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService",
                    "priority": -500
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

**Binding**

```
"PushMessageManager": {
        "pushEnabled": true,
        "debugInfo": {
            "senderId": "myid......(same one)",
            "deviceToken": null,
            "firebaseApps": [],
            "c2dmReceiver": [
                {
                    "name": "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver",
                    "priority": 0
                }
            ],
            "instanceIdService": [],
            "messagingService": [
                {
                    "name": "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService",
                    "priority": -500
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Everything else is pretty much the same. Does anyone know what may have caused **com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.MCFirebaseMessagingService** to be absent from **messagingService** and how it could be added? Thank you.

Comment: That service, and others, are declared in the manifest.  Does your merged manifest contain them?

Comment: @BillMote Yes, that's it! I was missing some important parts in my manifest. Thank you! I can now add them in my binding with Additions:

`namespace Com.Salesforce.Marketingcloud.Messages.Push
{
    [Service(Exported = false)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" }, Priority = -1)]
    public partial class MCFirebaseMessagingService
    {
    }
}`

Comment: Care to publish your whole binding file here for everyone or linking to your repo for the binding file?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your merged manifest has all the receivers & services that would be declared by the SDK in a native implementation.